# What would be a better way to insert foreign key relations using mysql.connector?

Tags: python, mysql, foreign-keys

I want to connect two tables using a foreign key.

```
my_cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)
Q3 ="INSERT INTO bookings(userID, posts) VALUES (%s, %s)"
Q4 = "SELECT userID from users where username=%s"
my_cursor.execute(Q3, ((Q4, username), posts))
db.commit()
```

I get the following error.

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 626, in prepare_for_mysql
    result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type tuple cannot be converted
```

Which makes sense I guess, because I am inserting a tuple in when I type `(Q4, userID)`.

How do I insert the value while referencing it as a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that, for a replacement of a place holder.

This query will fail if the username is not `UNIQUE`, it is only allowed to return 1 id

And i also added teh my_cursor definition, because you didn't provide yours

```
my_cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
Q3= "INSERT INTO bookings(userID, posts) VALUES ((SELECT userID from users where username=%s), %s);"
my_cursor.execute(Q3, ( username, posts))
db.commit()
```

Comment: Ok, I thought it would look neater if could break up the code into smaller bits and pieces, but if that is the case, thanks for the reply.